# Add path on rectangle element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid, addition

I have a chess board, I chose `UniformGrid` layout and filled it with rectangles. Now when i click on rectangle i want to add `Path` element (chess piece)  on rectangle. How I could do this because rectangle don't have `Children.Add()` method. Also I want to know how I could remove piece when I clicked again.

Comment: Post some XAML code here.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to layer your chess pieces on top on your `UniformGrid` and calculate their position manually. For example, to put a piece on **b4** you can try something like this:

```
<Grid>
   <UniformGrid></UniformGrid>
   <!-- Add piece paths here -->
</Grid> 


Path myChessPiece = new Path();
double lengthOfSquare = 24.0;
int positionX = 2;
int positionY = 4;

Canvas.SetTop(myChessPiece, positionY * lengthOfSquare);
Canvas.SetLeft(myChessPiece, positionX * lengthOfSquare);
```